# Reducible representation of SO(2)

Tags: group-theory

I was reading about groups, but i am a little confused: Jones' book states that the $SO(2)$ representation

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \phi & - \sin \phi \\
\sin \phi & \cos \phi
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Is irreducible over $R$, but reducible over $C$.

I am not sure how to show that. I mean, we can realize that a rotation is $C$ is only $\theta \rightarrow \theta + \theta'$, and so notice that $r$ remains invariant.

But i want to know how to show the (ir)reduciblity using only the matrix. I mean, theorically a representaition is reducible if it can be put in bloc (upper) diagonal right? How do i reduce the rotation matrix to upper diagonal (in complex field)?

Comment: Over $\mathbb C$ the matrix can be diagonalized.  I suggest you calculate its characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the comment above. To see that this representation is reducible over $\mathbb{C}$ you can just find a common eigenvector in $\mathbb{C}^2$ for all elements. This uses the following useful linear algebraic fact:

*If $A$ and $B$ are commuting matrices and $V_\lambda$ is a $\lambda$ eigenspace of $A$ then $B$ preserves $V_\lambda$.*

If you haven't seen this before it is a fun little exercise.

It is easy to check that the vector $(1,-i)$ spans the 1-dimensional $i$-eigenspace of

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Your representation is abelian, and so by the above fact this is an eigenvector of every element of your representation. This shows that the representation is reducible over $\mathbb{C}$.

Since the representation is 2-dimensional to show that it is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$ you just need to show that there are no invariant 1-dimensional subspaces, but this is just the same as showing that some element has no real eigenvectors. This is straightforward to check.

As a quick aside I should mention that any representation that is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$ either stays irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$ or splits into a pair of irreducible conjugate representations. Yours is an example of the latter phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

One can use the following equality true for all $\phi$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & i \\
i & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \phi & - \sin \phi \\
\sin \phi & \cos \phi
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & i \\
i & 1
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\phi+i\sin\phi & 0 \\
0 & \cos\phi-i\sin\phi
\end{pmatrix}
$$